# After storing (many) elements in Panel, including multiple UpdatePanels, how do I access a Label inside UpdatePanel inside Panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, updatepanel

How do I access label {"lblStaticText_" + i.ToString()} below, which is stored in a UpdatePanel, and then in a Panel, when button "btncomment_..." is pressed, causing an UpdatePanel to fire, to add a comment?

(Comment stores successfully - just can't get ahold of Label to update on the page. :-|

.aspx:

```
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <table style="width: 100%;" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 49%;"></td>
                        <td style="width: 2%;">
                            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="divMain" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 49%;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

.aspx.cs

This is a table that is inside of an UpdatePanel:

```
            var up = new UpdatePanel();
            up.ID = "UpdatePanel_" + i.ToString();
            up.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;

            var lbl0 = new Label();
            lbl0.ID = "lblStaticText_" + i.ToString();
            lbl0.Text = "test";

            var lbl1 = new Label();
            lbl1.Text = "Add a comment!: ";

            var tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = "comment_" + i.ToString();
            tb.Attributes["placeholder"] = "Stuff";
            tb.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
            tb.Rows = 3;
            tb.Columns = 35;

            var btn = new Button();
            btn.ID = "btncomment_" + strpicture_name.Replace(".", "~") + "_" + i.ToString();
            btn.Text = "Submit";
            btn.Click += btn_All;

            var Table2 = new Table();
            Table2.ID = "ctbl_" + i.ToString();
            //Table2.Style.Add("width", "300px");
            Table2.Style.Add("width", "100%");
            Table2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            Table2.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            Table2.BorderWidth = 1;
            Table2.CellPadding = 0;
            Table2.CellSpacing = 3;

            //first row
            TableRow tRowc = new TableRow();
            Table2.Rows.Add(tRowc);

            TableCell tCellc = new TableCell();
            tCellc.Style.Add("vertical-align", "top");
            tCellc.Style.Add("padding", "10px");

            tCellc.Controls.Add(lbl0);

            tRowc.Cells.Add(tCellc);

            //second row
            tRowc = new TableRow();
            Table2.Rows.Add(tRowc);

            tCellc = new TableCell();
            tCellc.Style.Add("border", "1px solid black");
            tCellc.Style.Add("vertical-align", "top");
            tCellc.Style.Add("padding", "10px");
            tCellc.Style.Add("width", "300px");

            tCellc.Controls.Add(lbl1);

            tRowc.Cells.Add(tCellc);

            TableCell tCellc1 = new TableCell();
            tCellc1.Style.Add("border", "1px solid black");
            tCellc1.Style.Add("vertical-align", "top");
            tCellc1.Style.Add("padding", "10px");
            tCellc1.Style.Add("width", "300px");

            tCellc1.Controls.Add(tb);

            tRowc.Cells.Add(tCellc1);

            TableCell tCellc2 = new TableCell();
            tCellc2.Style.Add("border", "1px solid black");
            tCellc2.Style.Add("vertical-align", "top");
            tCellc2.Style.Add("padding", "10px");
            tCellc2.Style.Add("width", "300px");

            tCellc2.Controls.Add(btn);

            tRowc.Cells.Add(tCellc2);

            up.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(Table2);

            tCell.Controls.Add(up);

            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

            i++; --repeat--
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the findcontrol function to get child elements by name in your code behind. Use it multiple times to find nested controls like your panels and label. For example:

```
Dim p as panel = page.findcontrol("panelname")
Dim l as label = p.findcontrol("labelname")
```